# Titan X with Precision T1700

Tags: graphics-card

Can I put a single Nvidia Geforce GTX Titan X in my Dell Precision T1700.

Here are some details about my configuration in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/abojchevski/b3a80d197dbd03d28368fdef86a85373

It says Up until 90% efficiency 365W, (Thunderbolt compatible).

Comment: The GeForce Titan X’s TDP is around 250W.  If you have a 365 W power supply, on top of the rest of your hard, and factor out the fact the maximum power load your current PSU is lower then 365 W its very unlikely your system could handle a Titan X without you upgrading the PSU also.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you'd be pushing it with that PSU. [This link](http://www.pcper.com/reviews/Graphics-Cards/NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-TITAN-X-12GB-GM200-Review/Overclocking-Power-Consumption-N) shows a test system with this card drawing 375 watts.

Test system setup:

```
CPU               Intel Core i7-3960X Sandy Bridge-E  
Motherboard       ASUS P9X79 Deluxe  
Memory            Corsair Dominator DDR3-1600 16GB  
Hard Drive        OCZ Agility 4 256GB SSD  
Sound Card        On-board  
Graphics Card     NVIDIA GeForce GTX TITAN X 12GB  
Graphics Drivers  NVIDIA: 347.84  
Operating System  Windows 8 Pro x64
```